# How to record a sound and play it with delay?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I know that i can record sounds by Media Player component, but after record i have to save it and then play it. But is there any way to play it instantly or with a custom delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with [LakeofSoft VC components](http://lakeofsoft.com/vc/a_voicerecording.html). Their [voice recording demo](http://lakeofsoft.com/vc/a_voicerecording.html) works like you want.

Comment: I didn't use but you can look Wave Audio Package(http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-packages/waveaudio/) of Delphi Area

Answer (score 2):

You might try the audio library at: http://www.un4seen.com/

The "BASS" DLLs work fine with Windows Xp and Win 7.  They are free for non-commercial use. The download includes a simple Delphi example of an audio recorder that allows one to "record," then "save" as an audio file or "playback" the file immediately without saving the audio file while the audio file is still in memory.   "BASS" works very well with Delphi 2007.  It might work great for your purposes.

Comment: @yesterday and @SimaWB; the components and dll you introduced were really great, but unfortunately i could not find what im looking for, can you help me in another way please?

Comment: @Armin  Download bass24.zip.  Unzip the package.  Go to the 'delphi' folder, then the 'RecordTest' folder.  Return to the main package folder, copy the bass.dll and paste it into the RecordTest folder. Left Double-Click the RecordTest.dpr.  This starts your compiler. Load the example.  Run the example.  This does what you ask for using the bass.dll.  The Record button records.  The Play button plays back what you just recorded from memory.  The Save button saves to a file. Can something similar be done with tMediaPlayer? Perhaps.  You will have to add custom code to the event handlers.

Comment: @SteveJG! i know how to use BASS.DLL and how to run my compiler! i checked all demo programs and 'Record Test' too before you describe how to do it. as i said i want to record the voice and play it instantly (or with 0.5s delay) but 'RecordTest' did not work as i want, you can not listen to your recorded voice instantly(or i couldnt make it), the problem is here, not TO RUN COMPILER!!! hope it be clear this time. by the way BASS.DLL is amazing, thanks for that

Comment: @Armin    There appears to be a problem understanding what you mean by "play it instantly or with a custom delay."   Detailed instructions were provided because you said "unfortunately i could not find what im looking for, can you help me in another way" seemed to imply you could not find the example...evidently you can.  You do not have to be nasty.  "you can not listen to your recorded voice instantly(or i couldnt make it)," I suggest you try harder...it works here.

Comment: you are right and i am sorry for that.... you told me "it work here", what do you mean? your compiler runs it and you can just execute it or you can play it with delay too? my problem is in second part, i can compile, run it and execute it with no problem, everything is just fine, nut i can not change it to play recorded sound while im recording...

Comment: It compiles and runs from the compiler or the exe the compiler creates and works on Xp and Win7. The compiled exe must be in a folder with the bass.dll to run. You need to 'tell' your software when the 'Record to memory' is finished. In the example, you do this manually (Play button) where audio is saved only to memory. You need to code something like VOX. The example lacks an automatic 'Play with delay' feature. Add one with a timer/ DLL event handler to execute the 'Play'routine.

Comment: @Armin You did not originally mention the need to "play recorded sound while im recording" Edit your question to indicate you want to "mix" the audio recorded in memory to a second record (to memory?) or playing audio file.  It is not clear which you want to do.  There are several BASS 'helper' modules that may help you here...for example there is a mixer DLL on the unseen site. There is a Help forum on the web page that might be a great place to restate your question w.r.t. BASS.   Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with bass.dll from http://www.un4seen.com/

You can use the RecordTest example from un4seen and modify the following functions like this:

```
function RecordingCallback(Handle: HRECORD; buffer: Pointer; length: DWORD; user: Pointer): boolean; stdcall;
begin
  BASS_StreamPutData(chan, buffer, length); // added: pass the captured data to the push stream
    // Copy new buffer contents to the memory buffer
    Form1.WaveStream.Write(buffer^, length);
    // Allow recording to continue
    Result := True;

    Form1.WaveStream.Write(WaveHdr, SizeOf(WAVHDR));
    chan := BASS_StreamCreate(44100, 2, 0, STREAMPROC_PUSH, nil); // added: create a push stream
    BASS_ChannelPlay(chan, False); // added: start it
    // start recording @ 44100hz 16-bit stereo
end;


procedure TForm1.StopRecording;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    BASS_ChannelStop(rchan);
    BASS_StreamFree(chan); // added: free the push stream
    bRecord.Caption := 'Record';
    // complete the WAV header
    WaveStream.Position := 4;
    i := WaveStream.Size - 8;
    WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
    i := i - $24;
    WaveStream.Position := 40;
    WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
    WaveStream.Position := 0;
    // create a stream from the recorded data
    chan := BASS_StreamCreateFile(True, WaveStream.Memory, 0, WaveStream.Size, 0);
    if chan <> 0 then
    begin
        // enable "Play" & "Save" buttons
        bPlay.Enabled := True;
        bSave.Enabled := True;
    end
    else
        MessageDlg('Error creating stream from recorded data!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
end;
```

When you press record after the modification, It plays the sound at the same time while recording it.

I got this code from Ian in the forum.